# Passing coroutine function as function parameter

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, higher-order-functions

I need to pass a coroutine function as a parameter for another function. For example:

```
private fun handleIt(here: Long, call: (hereId: Long) -> Unit) {
            call(here)
}
```

and then from the coroutine scope:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
                        handleIt(3) { viewModel.doThings(hereId) }
                    }
```

The viewModel function looks like this:

```
suspend fun doThings(hereId: Long) {
        withContext(coroutineContextProvider.io) {
            doSomething(hereId)
        }
    }
```

But now, I got the error: "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body. Any suggestions?

Comment: Example doesn't make much sense. How `doSomething()` is related to everything else?

Comment: this is no real code. It should just show the problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple solution would be to mark both the block and `handleIt` function as suspending:

```
suspend fun handleIt(here: Long, call: suspend (hereId: Long) -> Unit) {
    call(here)
}
```

Comment: great! didn't know that this syntax is properly right, thank you!